# Recommended settings for ColorFabb Copperfill Filaments on a 0.25 mm Nozzle?

Tags: pla, ultimaker-2, filled-pla

I switched out my 0.4 mm Ultimaker 2+ Nozzle the other day for the 0.25 mm and started using a ColorFabb Copperfill 2.85 mm filament. I am having some issues with it clogging and sticking to the bed for larger prints:

[image: Snapshot of 1st Layer]

Current settings are:

- Extruder Temp: 230°C
- Flow Rate: 110% (increased it from 108% get more consistent output)
- Bed Temperature: 70°C

I thought it might be a calibration issue since I could see it skipping certain sections and slowly collecting excess material on the outer nozzle, so I recalibrated the bed but I still ended up with a blocked nozzle after about two hours of running. Not too sure if there are other settings I need to take care of. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: A more general title might help you get more visibility here. I doubt its specific to the exact materials, this is maybe more a question of debug after changing stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a problem with feeding filament. It could be good to know if you did try such big printouts before but even if - from your picture it looks like on far end there is too less filament but on near end it's too much of it (because of 110%). And near the big circle it looks better even on far end. And there are "waves" close to big circle.

**How is that possible?**

Assuming that your extruder works well it might be caused by bending bowden tube. If your filament is not slick enough - in some settings (positions/arrangements) of bowden it might create enough friction so it doesn't flow with proper rate. It might be also caused if your bowden tube was bent too much (broken).

To be sure please try to print 4 smaller (5 cm in diam) circles on bed's corners and the one in the center. Just one layer of course.

**How to fix the issue?**

In my opinion you could try to slow down whole printout. Try to print such big circle with 30% of regular speed. I'm pretty sure you'll get proper results.

Try to check if filament goes smoothly thought the tube. Check if it has proper inner diameter. You can try to clean up a tube inside if it's not perfect clean or change a tube to new one. I know it was probably ok for recent filaments but maybe this one is more "demanding" ;)

Comment: I agree it could be a feed problem. It might also relate to the filament getting stuck as it comes off the reel somehow (extrude speed related maybe)

Comment: Lowering print speed is probably a very good idea. Remember that using a smaller nozzle will markedly increase the extrusion pressure at the nozzle (and therefore also the extruder gear). You can find a suitable printing speed by by assuming your [volumetric pressure](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-can-i-calculate-volumetric-speed-for-slic3r-auto-speed) is constant (using parameters from a previous print with the 0.4 nozzle), lowering your extrusion width to match the new nozzle, and then balance print speed and layer height accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: It appears to have been the over-extrusion because it was only recommended for 108% flow. I've tried large prints as well, and upon closer inspection it appears that all of them have the same marking pattern as above, but it's not apparent during printing. I suspect it may have something to do with the glass bed as the other prints were on 0.4 mm nozzles and I've recalibrated a number of times already. I've lowered the flow back down to 108% and although it's still not perfect, it doesn't look too bad :)

Comment: @ITTsoi it could not be too hard to check if your glass is ok using bubble level or... other piece of glass ;) (keep in mind it can bend while hot). But I still think these "waves" suggest something else than curved glass.